# Craft Panel Structure Duplication Issue

Tags: control-panel

Having a weird issue here.

I have a structure field inside my section on my panel which is divided up by headings.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to collapse a heading via the panel, it doesn't have any effect. It doesn't collapse and sometimes it makes a duplicate of itself.

Its a hard issue to explain over text so I've created a small video to show the issue in action.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vv8vToRCUUw&feature=youtu.be

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Davabo! Nice job illustrating your problem with a video. Please consider accepting Lindsey's answer if you feel it sufficiently identified the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a quirky byproduct of two subtle features colliding...

**Lazy-loading index** - You don't immediately see the full list of elements. You'll need to keep scrolling down to reveal them all.

**JS-based collapsing** - Collapsing/expanding the tree is a client-side behavior. It uses JS to collapse/expand, then stores the current view in a session cookie.

The behavior is simply a minor local issue... it doesn't affect any actual data in your system. The only real solution is to **refresh the page** when you start seeing the weirdness. Your collapse/expand choices will be remembered, and the items will be reloaded as expected.